# I'm trying to echo an image in a PHP variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, echo

Hello I'm trying to echo an image on a view page in CodeIgniter but nothing is displayed on the page.

Here I'm making the variable:

```
<?php $image = "<img src='../../images/stoel.jpg' alt='img' />";  ?>
```

And here I'm trying to echo the image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>">
```

Comment: its not possible you echo whole image tag in src of another image tag. print only path of image



<?php $image = '../../images/stoel.jpg' ; ?>

and

<img src="<?php echo $image;?>">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean. Since you are echoing inside the `src` attribute, you do not need to store the whole `<image>`, just the path will do.

```
<?php 
    $image = "../../images/stoel.jpg";
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image;?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

## Intro

This is the most basic php, so what's the addition of this question? Please read the basics of `echo` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php (**Example 1**).

Learn the basics first!

## Solution

**1. Assign full html tag to variable and echo full html:**

```
<?php
    $image = '<img src="../../images/stoel.jpg" alt="Foo">';

    echo $image;
?>
```

**2. Or assign image path to variable and echo concat string:**

```
<?php
    $path = '../../images/stoel.jpg';

    echo '<img src="' . $path . '" alt="Foo">';
?>
```

**3. Or assign image path to variable and echo only this with php:**

```
<?php
    $path = '../../images/stoel.jpg';
?>

<img src="<?= $path; ?>" alt="Foo">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting full Image tag into src attribute.

```
<?php $image = "<img src='../../images/stoel.jpg' alt='img' />";  ?>

and

<?php echo $image; ?>
```

or

```
<?php $image = "../../images/stoel.jpg"; ?>

and

<img src="<?php echo $image;?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $image = "<img src='../../images/stoel.jpg' alt='img' />";  ?>
```

you try like this

```
<?php echo $image; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already assign full image code in variable so you just need to print your variable:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>">
```

To

```
<?php echo $image;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your images out side of the application folder then you can do something like

```
application

images

images > stoel.jpg

system

index.php
```

Use Base url from the [**url helper**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/stoel.jpg');?>" />
```

> **Make sure you have set the base_url in config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

You can also use HTML Helper [**img();**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img)